# $\xi$ is a root of multiplicity $2m-1$ of the equation $h(x)=f(x+f(x))-f(x)=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

If $\xi$ is a root of multiplicity $m$ of $f(x)=0$, then show that $\xi$ is a root of multiplicity $2m-1$ of the equation $$h(x)=f(x+f(x))-f(x)=0$$

And the conclude that $\xi$ is a simple root of the equation $$r(x)=\frac{f^2(x)}{h(x)}=0$$

Discuss about the disadvantages of applying Newton–Raphson method to $r(x)$.

---

If $\xi$ is a root with multiplicity $m$ of $f(x)$, then $f(x)=(x−\xi)^m\vartheta(x)$, with $\vartheta(\xi)≠0$. So here $$h(x)=f(x+f(x))-f(x)=$$

$$(x+(x−\xi)^m\vartheta(x)−\xi)^m\vartheta(x+(x−\xi)^m\vartheta(x))-(x−\xi)^m\vartheta(x)=0$$

I don't know how to conclude that $\xi$ is a root of multiplicity $2m-1$ of the equation $h(x)=0$ and so cannot use that to show that it's a simple root of $r(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Taylor polynomial with remainder term of $h$,
$$
f(x+v)-f(x)=f'(x)v+O(v^2)\implies h(x)=f'(x)f(x)+O(f(x)^2)
$$
which has the required multiplicity in its first term, $m-1$ in $f'$ at $ξ$ and $m$ in $f$, and also a larger multiplicity in the error term.

Comment: You are assuming differentiability.

Comment: Yes of course, how else will you define the multiplicity?

Comment: What about its radius of convergence? E.g. if $f(x)$ has a Taylor expansion with RC $|x|<a$ then by expanding $f(x+f(x))$ you are assuming that $|f(x)|<a$ which is not guaranteed.

Comment: The argument only uses the continuity of the second derivative, not the full series expansion.

Comment: I see (+1) ${}{}$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could you please explain what is $v$? Why does it have "the required multiplicity in its first term"?

Comment: @mali1234 : $v=f(x)$ inside the argument, renamed to make the Taylor polynomial obvious. The first term has order $(m-1)+m=2m-1$ in $(x-\xi)$ as claimed, the remainder term has order $2m$ or higher, thus not changing the order on the left side.